# Integer Overflow w/ Multiplication in C

Tags: c, integer, overflow, multiplication

I've recently been messing around with C and have come to the concept of integer overloading. I'm trying to create a program that detects whether or not two 32 bit integers multiplied by each other will be able to fit into another 32 bit integer.

I understand the concept of integer overflow and how integers end up overflowing, but I'm stuck with figuring out the logic for this program. Here's what I have so far:

```
int main() {    
int min = INT_MIN;
int max = INT_MAX;

int num1, num2;
int x = num1 * num2;

printf("Please enter a number you would like to multiply: ");
scanf("%d", &num1);
printf("\nPlease enter a second number you would like to multiply: ");
scanf("%d", &num2);

if (num1 > max / num2){
    printf("\nOverflow! - first case\n");
}
else if (num2 > max / num1){
    printf("\nOverflow! - second case\n");
}
else if ((num1 > max - num2 && num2 > 0 ) || 
     (num1 < max - num2 && num2 < 0)){

    printf("\nOverflow! - third case\n");
}
else
    printf("\nNot Overflow!\n");

return 0;
}
```

As you can see, my program can detect some cases for overflow, but several other cases like -2 * 3 and -2 * -3 will get caught by my conditions.

So what I have will absolutely not work. What are good ways to go about solving this?

Comment: [Test if arithmetic operation will cause undefined behavior](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/93687/29485) may help.

Answer (score 3):

An integer overflows when `a*b > INT_MAX` or when `a*b < INT_MIN`.

This leads to the inequations:

If `b > 0`: `a > INT_MAX/b` or `a < INT_MIN/b`
If `b < 0`: `a < INT_MAX/b` or `a > INT_MIN/b`

So the condition which outputs if an `int` overflows is:

```
b>0 && (a>INT_MAX/b || a<INT_MIN/b) || b<0 && (a<INT_MAX/b || a>INT_MIN/b)
```

Since here `INT_MIN/b` could overflow itself (when `b=-1`) this should be checked seperately.

This is a rather long condition and should maybe be splitted up and put into a function:

```
int ismultoverflow(int a, int b)
{
    if(b > 0)
    {
        if(a>INT_MAX/b || a<INT_MIN/b)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if(b < 0)
    {
        if(b == -1)
        {
            return a==INT_MIN;
        }

        if(a<INT_MAX/b || a>INT_MIN/b)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Another approach would be to group the inequations into four domains rather than two:

If `a > 0` and `b > 0`: `a > INT_MAX/b`
If `a > 0` and `b < 0`: `b < INT_MIN/a`
If `a < 0` and `b > 0`: `a < INT_MIN/b`
If `a < 0` and `b < 0`: `b < INT_MAX/a`

which leads to a function where you do not have to handle a special case:

```
int ismultoverflow(int a, int b)
{
    if(a>0 && b>0 && a>INT_MAX/b)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(a>0 && b<0 && b<INT_MIN/a)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(a<0 && b>0 && a<INT_MIN/b)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(a<0 && b<0 && b<INT_MAX/a)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course if you could use types with larger width it is way less complicated (it is not guaranteed that `long` or `long long` are wider than `int`, but on many platforms this is the case):

```
int ismultoverflow(int a, int b)
{
    long x=a, y=b;

    if(x*y > INT_MAX || x*y < INT_MIN)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In last version, you probably meant long long instead of long. In most modern computers, long has the same size as int. It could also be possible to use double.

Comment: @AlainMerigot At least on my machine (x86_64 linux with gcc) `int` is `32` bits and `long` is `64` bit, but that of course may differ. Even `long long` is not guaranteed to be wider than `int`, but I added it as possibility. Yes but I dislike the idea of solving `int` problems with floating point math, because in may cases this is a bad idea (currency for example).